# A lot of named arguments vs. **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, args, convention, keyword-argument

I know this question has been asked a few times in a few different ways, but none of them really address what my question is. I have a function that takes a hefty amount of arguments *and it is not doing too much*. It simply takes arguments that will be passed in from a device, then plots them on a table in reportlabs. So my question is: Is it better to have all 10 variables passed in as named arguments or would it be better to use **kwargs. I will always know the type of data being passed in.

Comment: Are you _defining_ the function or _calling_ the function? If defining, the real question you should be asking is whether you care about the explicitness of the function signature that is being called. Providing explicit list of arguments will let users of the function know exactly what's supported, doing a `**kwargs` will not have that, but makes it easier to define the function. If calling, you can just pass a `dict` as `**kwargs` and hope that the function will do what you expect.

Comment: I'm defining it and then later in the script calling it to build the table. It is working fine so no issues or anything, it was more of a conventional question if anything. For anyone who might work on this in the future it would likely make more sense to have them all as named arguments.

Comment: It really depends on what you favor: correctness or simplicity. `**kwargs` with `.get('key', default)` will allow potentially unwanted arguments, but dramatically simplify the function signature. If you want to favor correctness, you should probably explicitly supply the allowed keywords.